# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' while deploying to ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

Tried multiple solutions online but couldnt get it working !
Basically my application is deployed but http response is "Internal Server Error".
On investigating EB logs i found the following traceback.

```
[Sat Jun 08 10:28:56.880823 2019] [:error] [pid 4776] [remote 172.31.4.251:180] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Jun 08 10:28:56.880846 2019] [:error] [pid 4776] [remote 172.31.4.251:180]   File "/opt/python/current/app/modelforms/modelforms/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Sat Jun 08 10:28:56.880863 2019] [:error] [pid 4776] [remote 172.31.4.251:180]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sat Jun 08 10:28:56.880878 2019] [:error] [pid 4776] [remote 172.31.4.251:180] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[Sat Jun 08 10:29:10.828039 2019] [:error] [pid 4776] [remote 172.31.42.54:180] mod_wsgi (pid=4776): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/modelforms/modelforms/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Jun 08 10:29:10.828089 2019] [:error] [pid 4776] [remote 172.31.42.54:180] mod_wsgi (pid=4776): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/modelforms/modelforms/wsgi.py'.
```

My requirements.txt is placed in all directories and yet django module is not recognised. It seems it hasn't been installed at first place. 
The file's contents are:

```
Django==2.2.1
Pillow==6.0.0
pytz==2019.1
sorl-thumbnail==12.5.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT1:
I dont have ebextentions setup, however the same config's are present when i run " eb config"

```
 aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    NumProcesses: '1'
    NumThreads: '15'
    StaticFiles: /static/=static/
    WSGIPath: modelforms/modelforms/wsgi.py
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles:
    /static/: static/
aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:
    EnvironmentType: LoadBalanced
    ExternalExtensionsS3Bucket: null
    ExternalExtensionsS3Key: null
    LoadBalancerType: application
    ServiceRole: aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role
```

Comment: please show your config files

Comment: Are you talking about the output from " eb config " ?. Just FYI, i had changed my WSGI path pointing to my application wsgi.py file in the same "eb config" file.

Comment: within `.ebextensions` you may have a number of config files.  Somewhere in them you'll be specifying `"aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":` and `"aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":`.  Please show these config files

Comment: please check my edit

Comment: Don't you have any file in ".ebextensions"? So where do you run migrations or generate statics?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and PYTHONPATH to the config

```
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "modelforms.settings"
    "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/app/modelforms:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Also, check the Health dashboard and make sure it shows as deployed before testing